# How to dynamically change the selected option and update without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html-select, onload, content-script

It was hard to find terms for a good search (so please excuse me if the topic has already been discussed) as well as an explicit title for this post.

I'm working on this external web page : https://espacepersonnel.bnf.fr/views/mes_notices.jsf (need to be logged)
and I'm trying to override the default selected option with the one which value="0". The custom js code I wrote does submit the form but only after the page has been loaded. Nevertheless I'd like to change the select value before this.

Here's the concerned code's part of this page (that of course I can't edit) :

```
<form id="noticeComp:mainForm" name="noticeComp:mainForm" method="post" action="/views/mes_notices.jsf" class="noticeForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="noticeComp:mainForm" value="noticeComp:mainForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="noticeComp:mainForm:j_idt253" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="noticeComp:mainForm:j_idt254" value="false">
    <!-- <div id="site"> -->    
    <!-- <div class="moncatagen"> -->
    <!-- <div class="col2"> -->
    <h1 class="h1small">
        <span>
            <select name="noticeComp:mainForm:j_idt256" size="1" onchange="submit()">
                <option value="0">Toutes les notices</option>
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Notices biblio.</option>
                <option value="2">Notices d'autorités</option>
            </select>               
            Notices
        </span>
    </h1>
</form>
```

And here's my own 'content_script' :

```
var elm;
var evt;

elm = document.getElementsByName('noticeComp:mainForm:j_idt256')[0];
evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);

    while(!document.getElementsByName('noticeComp:mainForm:j_idt256')[0].options[0].selected){
        document.getElementsByName('noticeComp:mainForm:j_idt256')[0].options[0].selected="selected";
        elm.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
```

Can you see a solution for me ? (Better if JS only)

Thank you very much for reading this post and answering it if you can.

Bigindian.

P.S : Pardon my english

N.B :
Result page :

[result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdSWM.jpg)

Comment: javascript cannot be initialised before the page loads. Javascript is a client side only language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

- get a reference to the select
- loop over its options
- if the value of the option is '0', select it. Otherwise, deselect it.

Example code:

```
var elm = document.getElementsByName('noticeComp:mainForm:j_idt256')[0];
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);

for (var i = 0; i < elm.options.length; i++) {
    var option = elm.options[i];

  if (option.value === '0') {
    option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
  } else {
    option.removeAttribute('selected');
    }
}

elm.dispatchEvent(evt);

function submit() {
    // code
  console.log('gogo');
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ufe9htvv/1/)**

Comment: Well, my script is able to select the right option and then refresh the results by submitting the form. What I'd like to do is displaying the results associated to the option value "0" ("Toutes les notices") at the first loading of this page !

Comment: Before the submit? And where would you like to display that text?

Comment: I added a picture of the result list, I can give you the code part but it's messy (big table)

Comment: I don't get it. If the option is selected, it is already displayed in the select, right?

Comment: My bad, it wasn't clear enough.
Let's start from scratch !
When I load the page, I see the results which correspond to the value of the defaultSelected option ("1").
My code changes the selected option to "0" and triggers the 'change' event which triggers the 'submit' one. So the page has loaded a first time with wrong result list and then load again to refresh with the right option selected.
The page takes 2 seconds to load, so with this reload it isn't useful to have a custom script, I can do the same clicking the dropdown list and selecting the right option !

Comment: You cannot initialize javascript before page loads. Javascript is client-side only. @BigIndian66

Comment: In that case maybe the best thing to do is show the right data at first pageload

Comment: @RohitAgre : Duly noted, too bad ! :(

Comment: @Pimmol as I said, the website isn't mine, I can't edit the HTML, it would be so simple ! :/